# How to set the $dirty and $invalid state of the dropdown basis on the other drop down value

Tags: angularjs

I have two dropdowns on which I am applying angular form validations.

```
    <form name="newForm" data-ng-submit="save(newForm.$valid)" novalidate="novalidate">
        <select ng-model="val.selectOne" name="selectOne" ng-change="setValidation(val.selectOne)" data-ng-class="{ 'error': newForm.selectOne.$dirty && newForm.selectOne.$invalid }" required="required">
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
            <option>E</option>
        </select>
           <div data-ng-messages="newForm.selectOne.$error" data-ng-show="newForm.selectOne.$touched || newForm.$submitted">
             <div class="error-message" data-ng-message="required">Please enter value</div>
           </div>
        <select ng-model="val.selectTwo" name="selectTwo" data-ng-class="{ 'error': newForm.selectTwo.$dirty && newForm.selectTwo.$invalid }" required="required">
            <option>Val1</option>
            <option>Val2</option>
            <option>Val3</option>
        </select>
            <div data-ng-messages="newForm.selectTwo.$error" data-ng-show="newForm.selectTwo.$touched || newForm.$submitted">
               <div class="error-message" data-ng-message="required">Please enter value</div>
            </div>

       <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

What I want is when user select options C and D I do not want my second dropdown to validate on save.
In my directive code:-

```
scope.setValidation = function (value){
    if (value == "C" || value == "D") {
        scope.newForm.selectTwo.$invalid = true;
        scope.newForm.selectTwo.$touched = true;
        scope.newForm.selectTwo.$dirty = true;
    }
}
```

I am trying to set the validation states true for C and D but that is not working. Can anyone tell me any efficient method for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom directive for this purpose in which you can check if user selects 'c' or 'd' and validate accordingly.And please provide the value attribute for your select options. Look at the code below.

```
<form name="newForm" data-ng-submit="newForm.$valid && save(newForm.$valid)" novalidate="novalidate">
    <select ng-model="val.selectOne" name="selectOne" data-ng-class="{ 'error': newForm.selectOne.$dirty && newForm.selectOne.$invalid }" required="required">
        <option value="A" >A</option>
        <option value="B" >B</option>
        <option value="C" >C</option>
        <option value="D" >D</option>
        <option value="E" >E</option>
    </select>
       <div data-ng-messages="newForm.selectOne.$error" data-ng-show="newForm.selectOne.$touched || newForm.$submitted">
         <div class="error-message" data-ng-message="required">Please enter value</div>
       </div>
    <select custom="{{val.selectOne}}" ng-model="val.selectTwo" name="selectTwo" data-ng-class="{ 'error': newForm.selectTwo.$dirty && newForm.selectTwo.$invalid }" required="required">
        <option value="Val1">Val1</option>
        <option value="Val2">Val2</option>
        <option value="Val3">Val3</option>
    </select>
        <div data-ng-messages="newForm.selectTwo.$error" data-ng-show="newForm.selectTwo.$touched || newForm.$submitted">
           <div class="error-message" data-ng-message="required">Please enter value</div>
        </div>
<div ng-if="newForm.selectTwo.$error.someerror && newForm.$submitted" >
       <div class="error-message" data-ng-message="required">Please dont select 'C' or 'D'</div>
    </div>



   <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>


app.directive("custom", [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        function customValidator(ngModelValue) {
            var limit = attr.custom;
            if (limit !='C' && limit != 'D') {
                ctrl.$setValidity('someerror', true);
            } else {
                ctrl.$setValidity('someerror', false);
            }


            return ngModelValue;
        }
        ctrl.$parsers.push(customValidator);

    }
  }
 }]);
```

The error will be shown if the user selects 'C' or 'D' from the first select box and submit the form.